# Как реализовать поиск по SQLite базе данных android приложения во фрагменте

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-search-view

Есть код, предназначенный для поиска по базе данных и вывода результатов поиска в recyclerView:

```
  @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
        private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()
        private val myAdapter: MyAdapter by lazy { MyAdapter() }
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
    //        val person = Person("Ana", "Brown", 38)
    //        mainViewModel.insertData(person)
    
            binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            binding.recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
    
            mainViewModel.readData.observe(this, {
                myAdapter.setData(it)
            })
    
        }
    
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
    
            val search = menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            val searchView = search?.actionView as? SearchView
            searchView?.isSubmitButtonEnabled = true
            searchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
    
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
            if(query != null){
                searchDatabase(query)
            }
            return true
        }
    
        private fun searchDatabase(query: String) {
            val searchQuery = "%$query%"
    
            mainViewModel.searchDatabase(searchQuery).observe(this, { list ->
                list.let {
                    myAdapter.setData(it)
                }
            })
        }
    
    }
```

Однако, если реализовать поиск так, что при переключении между вкладками приложения (разными фрагментами), поиск будет в каждой из них. Мне же нужно, чтобы возможность поиска была только в одной вкладке.
Проблема в том, что когда я пробую реализовать то же самое внутри фрагмента, получается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы некорректно сформулировали вопрос. Судя по всему у вас такая ситуация - в дефолтном стиле есть ActionBar в активити, в который вы добавили меню. Теперь же пытаетесь добавлять меню в этот ActionBar из фрагмента. Т.е. поиск и БД тут вообще не при чём. По сути вопроса - если хотите делать именно так (ИМХО это не удобно), то посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31935887/3212712) как. Скорее всего вам будет удобнее убрать ActionBar из активити и добавить через `Toolbar` отдельно в каждый фрагмент. Меню в таком случае программно можно будет через ссылку на `Toolbar` загружать.